# React - TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React, sorry if this is too basic.

I have an input form and I'm trying to handle submits and changes to it, like so:

```
import { editMenuFormRules } from './forms/form-rules.js';

class Seeds extends Component{
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        formData: {
          coffee:''
        },
        menu:[],
        editMenuFormRules:editMenuFormRules,

    };
    this.handleSubmitCoffees = this.handleSubmitCoffees.bind(this);
    this.handleBeanFormChange = this.handleBeanFormChange.bind(this);
  };

componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      this.getSeeds();
    }
  };

getSeeds(event) {
    const {userId} = this.props
    const options = {
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/seeds/${userId}`,
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
      }
    };
    return axios(options)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data.data)
      this.setState({
        menu: res.data.data[0].menu
      })
    })    
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
  };
```

for handling submit and form change, I have:

```
handleSubmitCoffees(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formType = this.props.formType
    const {userId} = this.props
    var headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
        }
    const data = {
      coffee: this.state.formData.coffee
    };
    if (formType === 'EditMenu' && this.state.menu.includes(this.state.formData.coffee)) {
      alert('This coffee already exists. Please add a new one.');
      return (<Redirect to='/seeds' />);
    };
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/edit_menu/${userId}`;
    axios.post(url, data, headers)
      .then((res) => {
        this.clearForm()
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
      if (formType === 'EditCoffee') {
        this.props.createMessage('Coffee edit failed.', 'Please review your entry');
      };
    });
  };
```

and:

```
handleBeanFormChange(event) {
    console.log(event)
    const obj = this.state.formData;
    obj[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(obj);
    this.validateForm();; 
  };
```

finally, my form:

```
<form onSubmit={ (event) => this.handleSubmitCoffees(event) }>
  <div className="field">
    <input
      name="coffee"
      className="input is-large"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Enter Coffee Name"
      value={this.state.formData.coffee}
      onChange={this.handleBeanFormChange}
     />
  </div>
</form>
```

when I input my **first** item at form, however, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
```

which points to this line:

```
> 150 | if (formType === 'EditMenu' && this.state.menu.includes(this.state.formData.coffee)) {
```

am I not defining `this.state.formData.coffee` when I press enter at form?

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried using `bind` in the constructor for that function too?

Comment: yes, just did it (refer to edit). error persists.

Comment: Can you show us the code for `validateForm`?

Comment: sure. please refer to edit. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here, where there is a `GET` request for 'menu' value:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      this.getSeeds(); ///// <------------
    }
  };
```

There was a malformed `json` response object at backend:

```
response_object = {
              'status': 'success',
              'message': 'User does not have a menu yet',
              'data': [{"id": user.id,
                        "seeds": user.seeds,
                        "content": template}]
            }

                        //"menu": [] //----> key, value was missing
```

Therefore, there was no 'menu' value being fetched, and that's what 'undefined' refers to:

```
//GET request at `getSeeds()`
this.setState({
        menu: res.data.data[0].menu // <----- undefined
      })
```

no `this.state.menu` could be set at `getSeeds()`, at all.

Adding `"menu": []` to `response_object` fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

```
const obj = this.state.formData;
obj[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
this.setState(obj); // <-- this is setting 'target.name: value'
```

This is effectively overwriting `formData`. I think what you are meaning to do is:

```
const obj = Object.assign({}, this.state.formData);
obj[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
this.setState({ formData: obj });
```

Do note that it's important to clone the `formData` object, as what you are doing is mutating the state, which is not desired.

Comment: thank you. I did what you suggested. bur same error persists....